# Get TrackNumber from TrackNumber column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xna

I am trying to play a song using thr XNA MediaPlayer class. I need to supply an `int`. How do I get the track number from the selected item's TrackNumber column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to dig in and get the `SubItem`'s `.Text` value of the selected item, like this:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs[Convert.ToInt32(list.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[trackNumberColumnNumber].Text)]);
```

Where `trackNumberColumnNumber` is to be replaced with the column number of the TrackNumber column.

And since you're using the `MediaPlayer` class in a Windows Forms application, don't forget to call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update();` before calling `MediaPlayer.Play();`.